# How to display/populate a table only based on selection table in Qliksense?

Tags: data-visualization, qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have two tables:

[image]

They are linked by `CustomerId`. Currently, I display both the tables on a sheet in Qlik and on selection of the `CustomerId` in the first table, the values in the second table are updated.

However I would like to start with an empty second table and fill it in/populate the table only on the selection of CustomerId in the first table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually have trigger on something being selected in specific table/chart but since selecting in chart actually is making a selection then you can have calculation conditions based on the selected value(s).

### Qlikview

When chart properties a open you can have calculation condition. For example:
`= GetSelectedCount("CustomerId") = 1`

[image: Chart properties]

You can overwrite the default error message by specifying the text in `Caclulation condiction unfulfilled` section:

[image: Custom error messages]

(Just to mention that the message can be an expression as well)

### Qlik Sense

The situation with Sense is similar:

- select the chart
- expand `Add-ons`
- expand `Data handling`
- Add the calculation condition
- once the calc condition is added the `Displayed message` input will appead
- enter some message in it to overwrite the default one

[image: Qlik Sense]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Do you have any resources that you recommend to learn Qlik?

Comment: Know there are some good books and videos available on PacktPub, so probably you can start from there. Ive started working with Qlik long time ago so personally havent checked the books/videos but know the guys that have written them